# How can I define KdPrint to DbgPrint?

Tags: c, debugging, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write macros for universal debugging.
How to define KdPrint to DbgPrint?

I am trying like this

```
#define KdPrint(x) do{DbgPrint x;}while(0)
```

In driver code

```
KdPrint(("Driver entry")); // normal syntax for KdPrint.

DbgPrint("Driver entry"); // normal syntax for DbgPrint.
```

if I compile I am getting error 4013:

> 'KdPrint' undefined; assuming extern returning int"

Answer (score 1):

```
#define KdPrint(x) do { DbgPrint(x); } while (0)
...
KdPrint("Driver entry");
```